# Getting Exception: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread No configs match configSpec

Tags: android, opengl-es, egl

I am using the below code for the MultiSampling to make the smooth edge. Below code is working on some mobile and other mobile I am getting exception '`No configs match configSpec`.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

```
package com.amplimesh.renderer;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGL10;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLDisplay;

import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.util.Log;

// This class shows how to use multisampling. To use this, call
//   myGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(new MultisampleConfigChooser());
// before calling setRenderer(). Multisampling will probably slow down
// your app -- measure performance carefully and decide if the vastly
// improved visual quality is worth the cost.
public class MultisampleConfigChooser implements GLSurfaceView.EGLConfigChooser {
    static private final String kTag = "GDC11";
    @Override
    public EGLConfig chooseConfig(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display) {
        mValue = new int[1];

        // Try to find a normal multisample configuration first.
        int[] configSpec = {
                EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
                EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6,
                EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5,
                EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
                // Requires that setEGLContextClientVersion(2) is called on the view.
                EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 4 /* EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT */,
                EGL10.EGL_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 1 /* true */,
                EGL10.EGL_SAMPLES, 2,
                EGL10.EGL_NONE
        };

        if (!egl.eglChooseConfig(display, configSpec, null, 0,
                mValue)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("eglChooseConfig failed");
        }
        int numConfigs = mValue[0];

        if (numConfigs <= 0) {
            // No normal multisampling config was found. Try to create a
            // converage multisampling configuration, for the nVidia Tegra2.
            // See the EGL_NV_coverage_sample documentation.

            final int EGL_COVERAGE_BUFFERS_NV = 0x30E0;
            final int EGL_COVERAGE_SAMPLES_NV = 0x30E1;

            configSpec = new int[]{
                    EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
                    EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6,
                    EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5,
                    EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
                    EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 4 /* EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT */,
                    EGL_COVERAGE_BUFFERS_NV, 1 /* true */,
                    EGL_COVERAGE_SAMPLES_NV, 2,  // always 5 in practice on tegra 2
                    EGL10.EGL_NONE
            };

            if (!egl.eglChooseConfig(display, configSpec, null, 0,
                    mValue)) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("2nd eglChooseConfig failed");
            }
            numConfigs = mValue[0];

            if (numConfigs <= 0) {
                // Give up, try without multisampling.
                configSpec = new int[]{
                        EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 5,
                        EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 6,
                        EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 5,
                        EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE, 16,
                        EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 4 /* EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT */,
                        EGL10.EGL_NONE
                };

                if (!egl.eglChooseConfig(display, configSpec, null, 0,
                        mValue)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("3rd eglChooseConfig failed");
                }
                numConfigs = mValue[0];

                if (numConfigs <= 0) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No configs match configSpec");
                }
            } else {
                mUsesCoverageAa = true;
            }
        }

        // Get all matching configurations.
        EGLConfig[] configs = new EGLConfig[numConfigs];
        if (!egl.eglChooseConfig(display, configSpec, configs, numConfigs,
                mValue)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("data eglChooseConfig failed");
        }

        // CAUTION! eglChooseConfigs returns configs with higher bit depth
        // first: Even though we asked for rgb565 configurations, rgb888
        // configurations are considered to be "better" and returned first.
        // You need to explicitly filter the data returned by eglChooseConfig!
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < configs.length; ++i) {
            if (findConfigAttrib(egl, display, configs[i], EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 0) == 5) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index == -1) {
            Log.w(kTag, "Did not find sane config, using first");
        }
        EGLConfig config = configs.length > 0 ? configs[index] : null;
        if (config == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No config chosen");
        }
        return config;
    }

    private int findConfigAttrib(EGL10 egl, EGLDisplay display,
            EGLConfig config, int attribute, int defaultValue) {
        if (egl.eglGetConfigAttrib(display, config, attribute, mValue)) {
            return mValue[0];
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public boolean usesCoverageAa() {
        return mUsesCoverageAa;
    }

    private int[] mValue;
    private boolean mUsesCoverageAa;
}
```

Comment: @Andon M. Coleman Please help me for this as well. I hope you will help me for this. I am using the OpenGl 1

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are requesting an EGL config that your test device doesn't support. Not all implementations support multisampling, so you would probably want to fall back to a format that's most likely to be supported on any device. Currently your fallback format is RGB565, and my guess is that it's not supported on some of your target devices. You could try RGBA8888 or RGBA4444 instead, so for instance:

```
configSpec = new int[] {
        EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE,        8,
        EGL10.EGL_GREEN_SIZE,      8,
        EGL10.EGL_BLUE_SIZE,       8,
        EGL10.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE,      8,
        EGL10.EGL_DEPTH_SIZE,      16,
        EGL10.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, 4, /* EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT */
        EGL10.EGL_NONE
};
```

As far as I know, RGBA8888 with 16-bit depth buffer should be available in most relatively recent GLES2 devices.

Comment: When I used the above configuration now I am getting `08-27 11:00:12.809: E/AndroidRuntime(5193): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No config chosen
` exception. Please go through my code for this

Comment: Oh right, if you made those changes, you'll also need to replace the `5` with a `8` on this line: `if (findConfigAttrib(egl, display, configs[i], EGL10.EGL_RED_SIZE, 0) == 5) {`. Looping through all returned formats shouldn't be required here though, you could just use the first unless you're picky.

Comment: I set the above as per you told and above RGB configuration but still it not going in the for loop `for (int i = 0; i < configs.length; ++i) {` . `configs.length` is zero

Comment: That's odd, since it sure looks like you would get an exception before that loop if numConfigs had remained at zero.

Comment: Its happening here. Where you think it can have exception before the loop. There is no exception even in the loop. I mean control not going in the loop then `EGLConfig config` is null so it giving error `No config chosen`. Please help me to solve this

Comment: I am using the Open Gl 1. `setEGLContextClientVersion(1);`. It might hint you to help me.

Comment: Well in that case, why are you using `EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT`? Your code even states "Requires that setEGLContextClientVersion(2) is called on the view."

Comment: Please help me the configuration for that. I got this code from google.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of very old issue, yet I found solution to this (at least in my case). So maybe someone will be able to find it helpful.

Problem was that emulator was using integrated graphics, instead of dedicated, which had no support for OpenGLES 2.0. So to solve it I had to force my emulator to use dedicated graphics. Just go to your graphics drivers and force them to use dedicated GPU instead of integrated.

In my case problem was solved :)